# Lamdeni chukecha. . . amen?

Tags: blessing, halacha, amen

When one is saying a *b'racha* and realizes only after saying God's name that the *b'racha* is no longer valid, he can avoid the problem of uttering God's name in vain by tacking on the words "למדני חקיך", thus transforming an aborted *b'racha* into a [fully-formed *pasuk*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%91).

If one hears another person use this fallback is it appropriate to respond with "אמן" as one would to a *b'racha*, or is the person simply quoting a *pasuk*, therefore not warranting such a response (like in the [case of ברכת כהנים](http://books.google.com/books?id=p2qC-G9wR1EC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=ken+yehi+ratzon&source=bl&ots=HOJMPEPopm&sig=D8mGznTrIAPzNzDPHWDQ5UAil4Q&hl=en&ei=p8rYTKiDDsL_lge_4Lm8CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false))?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3912/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well he only said a Posuk so why would you answer Amein? In regard to the issue raised as to this Pasuk being part of the Hadran at the end of a Mesechta and is followed by Amein If it was followed by the Kahal saying Amein then you would have a point. However it is part of the Nusach which the person who says the Hadran says, not the people hearing it responding with an Amein. It is similar to when we Daven Shacharis and say Boruch Hashem L'Olam and finish it with Amen V'amen. No one responds to it saying Amein. Here to you would not say Amein after the person finishes saying the Pasuk.

Comment: Not a good proof from Shacharit because there "Amen veAmen" is part of the original pasuk. See [Psalms 72:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2672.htm#19) and [Psalms 89:53](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2689.htm#53).

Answer (score 4):

By the *hadran* said after a *siyum* this Posuk is followed by Amen (more than one ...)

Comment: Anon_2Kislev71, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing this data to the table! Please change your username to a more distinctive pseudonym than the generic "Anon." I've taken the liberty of adding today's date to your name for the time being. Also, we'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Comment: If it was followed by the Kahal saying Amein then you would have a point. However it is part of the Nusach which the person who says the Hadran says, not the people hearing it responding with an Amein. It is similar to when we Daven Shacharis and say Boruch Hashem L'Olam and finish it with Amen V'amen. No one responds to it saying Amein. Here to you would not say Amein after the person finishes saying the Pasuk.

Answer (score 0):

like birkat cohanim, maybe you should say "ken yehi ratzon"

Comment: Do you say Kein Yehi Ratzon when someone says Ashrei? You only say it by Birchas Kohanim as you are affirming the Bracha. When there is no affirmation there is no Amein or Kein Yehi Ratzon.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Tehillim (eg., [תהלים פ"ט:נ"ג](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2689.htm#53)), you have the expression Amein v'Amein.  This is also Tehillim, so why not?

Comment: Adam, although I added the reference for you, I'm not sure I agree with you. In the case(s) you're referring to, it's part of the codified text of TaNa"Ch. In the case in the question, it would be the listener's response.