# When the entire Minyan is saying Kaddish

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, kaddish, amen

In most Synagogues all those that are required to say Kaddish say it together. If the entire Minyan has to say Kaddish and there is no one who can say Amein what should be done? Should some not say Kaddish and answer Amein instead? Should all say Kaddish and no one will be able to answer Amein? Is there a minimum required number of people who should answer Amein? (sources please)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13540

Answer (score 3):

From the Ben Ish Chai (end of [Parshas Vayachi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=63)):

> אות טז: … עוד נשאלתי שם בעשרה שלמדו תהלים ורוצים כלם לומר קדיש
>   שאין שום אחד עונה והבאתי דברי הרב בני יאודה עייאש ז״ל סי׳ ג׳ והארכתי
>   קצת בזה והעלתי דלכתחילה יזהרו להיות אחד עונה להם הקדיש׃

He cites the [Bnei Yehuda Siman 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1633&st=&pgnum=162) who writes about this and says that in a case when all are saying kaddish and no one can answer it is best to be careful initially to have one person answer the kaddish.

The Kaf Hachaim ([55:31](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8140&st=&pgnum=192)) cites this and the Ben Ish Chai but he ends off saying it seems that two are necessary (because "imru amein" is plural).

Comment: An English translation of the key sentences from the BIC would not only enhance the answer but make it more accessible for those who have limited hebrew skills but still want to know the halacha.

Comment: "he brings..." is a loose translation.

Comment: "that two are necessary (because "d'imru amein" is plural)" - Does "two" include or exclude the one saying the Kaddish? A follow up to this is being particular on the word "imru" which means -let us say. That would imply that if everyone is saying Kaddish, all of them are saying "Amen" as that is part of the Kaddish. If he requires two people to respond, the word should be "Ve'anu" - "they shall RESPOND".