# Can you say kaddish if some of the 10 people in the minyan are forbidden from answering?

Tags: halacha, kaddish, minyan, hefsek-interruption, speech-talking

If there are exactly 10 people in a minyan and one or more are forbidden from answering kaddish at that moment, is kaddish allowed to be recited? Examples of such a situation may include if someone is putting on tefillin, davening shmoneh esrei, needs to relieve himself etc.

Comment: Kaadish only requires 10 men to be present, not that they answer. So even if they can't answer, I don't see why they wouldn't count.

Comment: @rosenjcb do they count if they are asleep?

Comment: Highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13540/need-minyan-to-answer-kaddish

Comment: @user6641 Maybe, I'm not exactly sure... Oh Danny has an actual source!

Answer (score 9):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן טו - דיני קדיש וברכו וצרוף עשרה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2) says that as long as there are at least 6 people actually answering, **you may say Kaddish**, as long as there are 10 adult males above Bar Mitzva **awake** in the room - even if 1, 2, 3 or 4 of them are forbidden from answering kaddish at that moment.

> **סעיף ז'**: אִם אֵין ט' שׁוֹמְעִין לְהַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר, לֹא יֹאמַר כְּלָל קַדִּישׁ, כִּי כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁבִּקְדֻשָּׁה אֵין אוֹמְרִים בְּפָחוֹת מֵעֲשָׂרָה דְּהַיְנוּ אֶחָד אוֹמֵר וְתִשְׁעָה שׁוֹמְעִים, וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם, **אִם אֶחָד מֵהָעֲשָׂרָה מִתְפַּלֵּל תְּפִלַּת שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לַעֲנֹת עִמָּהֶם מִצְטָרֵף וְהוּא הַדִּין לְב' וְג' וְד'**, כָּל שֶׁנִּשְׁאַר הָרֹב שֶׁעוֹנִין, אֵין הַמִּעוּט מְעַכֶּבֶת, אֲבָל אִם אֶחָד מֵהֶן יָשֵׁן, צְרִיכִין לְהָקִיצוֹ, כִּי הַיָּשֵׁן אֵינוֹ מִצְטָרֵף לַעֲשָׂרָה. (נ"ו) ‏

Comment: I remember this being put to practice as well. One time a minyan showed up late and the chazan waited for at least 5 other people to finish shemone esrei before continuing on (my memory is a bit fuzzy though).