# Amen after hearing an identical blessing

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, hefsek-interruption, amen

If someone makes a blessing on food, and before eating hears the same blessing from another person, does he say Amen, or is that a hefsek?

Similarly, if one finishes Baruch She'amar, and (before continuing with Pesukei Dezimra) hears the *chazzan* finish it, should one respond Amen, or is that a hefsek as well?

Comment: I don't have the source ready right now, but one should not answer to a blessing on food (or anything else) between saying one's own identical blessing, and partaking. There is a disagreement on the matter though, and it is best to avoid the situation. A common case is someone else making _hamotzi_, while one has not partaken after his own blessing (or a blessing that was said on his behalf).

Comment: Sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8258

Answer (score -1):

On the blessing, it's a hefseck: you're in your blessing and mitzvah patiurs mitzvah. In pasick dzimra you can answer.