# Should we say Amen after the Harachamans in Bentching?

Tags: bentching, amen

I recently heard (cannot recall from who or if I saw it somewhere) that after each Harachaman (הרחמן) after the 4th Bracha in Birchas Hamazon, one should answer Amen. Additionally, I was bentching today after Shalosh Seudos, and I noticed this concept brought down in the Bentcher I was using.

Nonetheless, I have never seen this happen in practice. And in the Artscroll Birchon there is no mention of it.

So, what's up with this? Should we really be saying it? And if so, why has it fallen out of practice?

Comment: Possible superset: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/amen-to-informal-blessings-and-wishes

Answer (score 2):

I have no sources just life experiences.In certain Sephardi Homes I know this to be a standard custom I think it stems from they where in the custom of one person bentching for everyone.

Comment: Sefardim hold Lechatehila everyone should be bench from themselves, and even those who rely on the Shaat HaDehak most probably are relying on a non-mainstream opinion.

Comment: I'm actually Libyan :)

Comment: Yes, but not by so much. No, sorry. But if you take any other Edah you will find extremely similar customs- not such a big difference anyway.

Comment: The yes was that we have different customs on Halachot than Syrians. Yes, my grandmother (Shetichye) is from Tripoli.

Answer (score 1):

Shalah, Shaar HaOtiot Ot Kuf says to answer Amen after HaRahamim.

BN BH I will be back with some more sources.

More sources: Magen Avraham 189 and 215, Peri Megadim 124 (Orah Haim, Eshel Avraham), Mishna Berura 189 and 215, Elya Raba 187, Shulhan Aruch HaRav 189, Kisur Shulhan Aruch 44, Aruch HaShulhan 215, BeSel HaHochma 5:89, Yechawe Daat 3:9 and more.

I think the real question is, are you allowed to answer this type of Amen in the middle of Birkat HaMazon. I have an answer to that also :)