# Conservative Jews saying "amen" instead of saying Harachamans

Tags: bentching, heterodox, motzi-yedei-chovato

I've noticed that among Conservative Jews, it seems to be a common practice that one person recites the harachamans after Birkat Hamazon and others are silent and only respond "amen". Now, after one hears someone else say a "harachaman" in Birkat Hamazon it is proper to respond "amen" (see Mishnah Berurah 189:5), but I had assumed that one is supposed to recite the harachamans himself as well if he is bentching. Are these Conservative Jews acting improperly? Would the concept of shomea k'oneh apply here even though there is no real obligation to say the harachamans?

Comment: related: [tag:zimmun]

Comment: I once ate with *Teimanim* whose practice was for one person to say the whole *Birkat Hamazon* aloud, and for everyone else to just listen and answer "*Amen*," FWIW.

Comment: what @IsaacMoses has said. in my beith ha kannasath only one person says beerkath ha mozon and everyone else says omein to the barochoth and the hora7amon

Comment: @IsaacMoses I've eaten with Ashkenazim who do that too.

Comment: possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11731/759

Comment: Why would shomea k'oneh not apply in this case?  Is it really dependant on obligation, or does it just only make a difference if there is an obligation?  Wouldn't the דרבנן obligation be enough for it to matter?